# How to input text into MathML editior using selenium/webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, data-driven-tests

I am Using following code..

driver.switchTo().frame("editML");

```
WebElement editor = driver.findElement(By.className("#editML"));

JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '<h1>Heading</h1>Hello World'", editor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the text of the editor.

```
editor.sendKeys("<mi>a</mi>");
```